# Update variable value in module

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

*I'm a real newbie in node.js so pls understand my possible stupidity*

I'm trying to use a external file to serve as a module so I can use it in other files. The project is bigger than this but let's say my module is:

```
var Tools = module.exports = {
  result_arr: [],
  object_data: {
    times  : [],
    temps1 : [],
    temps2 : [],
    temps3 : [],
    temps4 : [],
    levels : [],
    flows  : []
  },
  getLastNRows: function (whereIsData, DB_info, table, NRows) {
    if (whereIsData == "MySQL") {
      function setValue (value) {
        Tools.result_arr = value;
      }
      function dataArray2Object (array_data) {
        Tools.object_data.times  = array_data.map(row => row.timestamp);
        Tools.object_data.temps1 = array_data.map(row => row.temp1);
        Tools.object_data.temps2 = array_data.map(row => row.temp2);
        Tools.object_data.temps3 = array_data.map(row => row.temp3);
        Tools.object_data.temps4 = array_data.map(row => row.temp4);
        Tools.object_data.levels = array_data.map(row => row.level_ice_bank);
        Tools.object_data.flows  = array_data.map(row => row.flow);
      }
      var queryString = "SELECT timestamp, temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, level_ice_bank, flow FROM " +
                        table + " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " + NRows + ";";
      var connnection = mysql.createConnection(DB_info);
      connnection.connect(function(err) {
        console.log("connected");
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      connnection.query(queryString, function (err, rows) {
        console.log("queried");
        if (err) throw err;
        setValue(rows);
        dataArray2Object(Tools.result_arr);
        console.log(Tools.result_arr);
        console.log(Tools.object_data);
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log("Function only accepts data stored in MySQL.\n(u still have to improve...)");
      return;
    }
};
```

The variable `object_data` is supposed to be used in a main file. This way, whenever I call `getLastNRows`, I expect `object_data` to be updated by the operations in `getLastNRows`. The main file would be:

```
var tools = require('./tools');

var where2save = "MySQL";
var info_db = {
  host    : "127.0.0.1",
  user    : "root",
  password: "xxxx",
  database: "mydb",
  port    : 3306
};
var table = "tempdata";
var NRows = 4;

tools.getLastNRows(where2save, info_db, table, NRows);

console.log(tools.object_data);
```

What is observed is that, in fact, `tools.object_data` is not updated by `getLastNRows` in the main file, although `console.log(Tools.object_data);` from the tools.js (module) file logs the updated values. So my question is:

How can I make `getLastNRows` update `tools.object_data` (which is empty when created) in the main file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `getLastNRows` asynchronous?  Cuz it seems to me that is the cause of the problem.

It calls the `getLastNRows` in main which then calls `connection.query`, which gets put on a worker thread then immediately continues to the `console.log` where `tools.object_data` has not been updated.

Try:

```
getLastNRows: function (whereIsData, DB_info, table, NRows, cb) {
    // ...
    connnection.query(queryString, function (err, rows) {
            console.log("queried");
            if (err) throw err;
            setValue(rows);
            dataArray2Object(Tools.result_arr);
            console.log(Tools.result_arr);
            console.log(Tools.object_data);
            cb()
    });
    // ...
}

// in main
tools.getLastNRows(where2save, info_db, table, NRows, function() {
    console.log(tools.object_data);
});
```

Comment: it probably is async (at least `connection.query()` is async). Do you know anyway to wait for `getLastNRows` to finish before the next code line is executed?

Comment: I just provided an update with a code snippet that should work.  You need to pass a callback into `getLastNRows`.  You may want to look into `Promises` or `async/await` if you're not stuck using an old node version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code worked! I know you answered what I've asked but that's not exactly what I really need. What I REALLY need is to store `tools.object_data` in a variable to be used in the next line (like `var foo = tools.getLastNRows(where2save, info_db, table, NRows, function() {return tools.object_data;});`)
OR
that the next line of code is just executed when the value of `tools.object_data` is updated.
Can you help me on that?

Comment: You would just continue execution in the callback and you can do whatever you need inside of there.

Comment: OK. So basically, whenever I have problems with some async functions and their execution order, the solution might be to pass nested callbacks, for each step of execution?

Comment: Yes, but again, you should really look into `Promises` or `async/await` if you're using a newish `node`. 

https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8

Comment: I will. Thanks a lot, your inputs allowed me to get the project going in the right direction.